# SEO returning very different results according to which country you look from

Tags: seo, google, international

A newbie question here. I just finished my first website for an artist and put in online. When I look for it by putting the name of the artist that the website is for, google returns the website fourth in the list (customer happy), but when they search for the same artist from France, the website is nowhere to be found, and only features on the fourth page (customer not happy). I was wondering why this is and how to correct it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

*Google results are personalised and search rankings are actually split into three categories:*

1. Local Rankings (Proximity to the Searcher)
2. National Rankings (Country Specific Results)
3. Global Rankings (Global Organic)

Also, Google can tailor results using cookies stored on the computer, so unless your using cookiless browsing, e.g Chrome incognito, I would not trust the reported results and its most likely worse than 4th page since Google favours sites that you have visited before.

*Test your global rankings using Cookiless browser*

So, unless you and your client are using cookiless browser then chances are your getting trailed results, for example:

Using Google.com then going to Google.de and searching for something then most of the results will be English, using a Cookiless browser and going to Google.de, your likely to get all Germany results.

*Different results from country to country*

Competition on keywords vary from country to country and it is that reason why you might rank well in one but not the other, because the competition is more or less.

*Improve Global Rankings*

To improve global rankings you need to gain more authority, generally natural SEO obtained from a good amount of geographic locations.

*Improve Country Specific Rankings*

If your targetting France then you need to ensure that your content is available in French since not all French people know English but more importantly you need French people buzzing about your site, on social media and forums for example.

*Summary...*

Tell your customer to improve his/her domain authority and offer multiple languages.